# Fourier transform or fit of sines and cosines to a 2D surface from discrete point cloud data

Tags: python, curve-fitting, point-clouds, surface

I have x,y,z data that define a surface (x and y position, z height).
The data is imperfect, in that it contains some noise, i.e. not every point lies precisely on the plane I wish to model, just very close to it.
I only have data within a triangular region, not the full x,y, plane.
Here is an example with z represented by colour:

[image: data]

In this example the data has been sampled in the centres of triangles on a mesh like this (each blue dot is a sample):

[image: mesh]

If it is necessary, the samples could be evenly spaced on an x,y grid, though a solution where this is not required is preferable.

I want to represent this data as a sum of sines and cosines in order to manipulate it mathematically. Ideally using as few terms as are needed to keep the error of the fit acceptably low.

If this were a square region I would take the 2D Fourier transform and discard higher frequency terms.

However I think this situation has two key differences that make this approach not viable:

1. Ideally I want to use samples at the points indicated by the blue dots in my grid above. I could instead use a regular x,y grid if there is no alternative, but this is not an ideal solution
2. I do not have data for the whole x,y, plane. The white areas in the first image above do not contain data that should be considered in the fit.

So in summary my question is thus:

Is there a way to extract coefficients for a best-fit of this data using a linear combination of sines and cosines? 
Ideally using python.

My apologies if this is more of a mathematics question and stack overflow is not the correct place to post this!

EDIT: Here is an example dataset in python style [x,y,z] form - sorry it's huge but apparently I can't use pastebin?:

```
[[1.7500000000000001e-08, 1.0103629710818452e-08, 14939.866751020554],
 [1.7500000000000001e-08, 2.0207259421636904e-08, 3563.2218207404617],
 [8.7500000000000006e-09, 5.0518148554092277e-09, 24529.964593228644],
 [2.625e-08, 5.0518148554092261e-09, 24529.961688158553],
 [1.7500000000000001e-08, 5.0518148554092261e-09, 21956.74682671843],
 [2.1874999999999999e-08, 1.2629537138523066e-08, 10818.190869824304],
 [1.3125000000000003e-08, 1.2629537138523066e-08, 10818.186813746233],
 [1.7500000000000001e-08, 2.5259074277046132e-08, 3008.9480862705223],
 [1.3125e-08, 1.7681351993932294e-08, 5630.9978116591838],
 [2.1874999999999999e-08, 1.768135199393229e-08, 5630.9969846863969],
 [8.7500000000000006e-09, 1.0103629710818454e-08, 13498.380006002562],
 [4.3750000000000003e-09, 2.5259074277046151e-09, 40376.866196753763],
 [1.3125e-08, 2.5259074277046143e-09, 26503.432370909999],
 [2.625e-08, 1.0103629710818452e-08, 13498.379635232159],
 [2.1874999999999999e-08, 2.5259074277046139e-09, 26503.430698738041],
 [3.0625000000000005e-08, 2.525907427704613e-09, 40376.867011915041],
 [8.7500000000000006e-09, 1.2629537138523066e-08, 11900.832515759088],
 [6.5625e-09, 8.8406759969661469e-09, 17422.002946526718],
 [1.09375e-08, 8.8406759969661469e-09, 17275.788904632376],
 [4.3750000000000003e-09, 5.0518148554092285e-09, 30222.756636780832],
 [2.1875000000000001e-09, 1.2629537138523088e-09, 64247.241146490327],
 [6.5625e-09, 1.2629537138523084e-09, 35176.652106572205],
 [1.3125e-08, 5.0518148554092277e-09, 22623.574247287044],
 [1.09375e-08, 1.2629537138523082e-09, 27617.700396641056],
 [1.5312500000000002e-08, 1.2629537138523078e-09, 25316.907231576402],
 [2.625e-08, 1.2629537138523066e-08, 11900.834523905782],
 [2.4062500000000001e-08, 8.8406759969661469e-09, 17275.796410700641],
 [2.8437500000000002e-08, 8.8406759969661452e-09, 17422.004617294893],
 [2.1874999999999999e-08, 5.0518148554092269e-09, 22623.570035270699],
 [1.96875e-08, 1.2629537138523076e-09, 25316.9042194055],
 [2.4062500000000001e-08, 1.2629537138523071e-09, 27617.700160860692],
 [3.0625000000000005e-08, 5.0518148554092261e-09, 30222.765972585737],
 [2.8437500000000002e-08, 1.2629537138523069e-09, 35176.65151453446],
 [3.2812500000000003e-08, 1.2629537138523065e-09, 64247.246775422129],
 [2.1875000000000001e-09, 2.5259074277046151e-09, 46711.23463223876],
 [1.0937500000000001e-09, 6.3147685692615553e-10, 101789.89315354674],
 [3.28125e-09, 6.3147685692615543e-10, 52869.788364220134],
 [3.2812500000000003e-08, 2.525907427704613e-09, 46711.229428833962],
 [3.1718750000000001e-08, 6.3147685692615347e-10, 52869.79233902022],
 [3.3906250000000006e-08, 6.3147685692615326e-10, 101789.92509671643],
 [1.0937500000000001e-09, 1.2629537138523088e-09, 82527.848790063814],
 [5.4687500000000004e-10, 3.1573842846307901e-10, 137060.87432327325],
 [1.640625e-09, 3.157384284630789e-10, 71884.380087542726],
 [3.3906250000000006e-08, 1.2629537138523065e-09, 82527.861035177877],
 [3.3359375000000005e-08, 3.1573842846307673e-10, 71884.398689011548],
 [3.4453125000000001e-08, 3.1573842846307663e-10, 137060.96214950032],
 [4.3750000000000003e-09, 6.3147685692615347e-09, 18611.868317256733],
 [3.28125e-09, 4.4203379984830751e-09, 27005.961455364879],
 [5.4687499999999998e-09, 4.4203379984830751e-09, 28655.126635802204],
 [3.0625000000000005e-08, 6.314768569261533e-09, 18611.869287539808],
 [2.9531250000000002e-08, 4.4203379984830734e-09, 28655.119850641502],
 [3.1718750000000001e-08, 4.4203379984830726e-09, 27005.959731047784]]
```

Comment: Yes, the trick would be though to get the periodicity right. As `sin` and `cos` are periodic function, do you want the fit to present a specific type of periodicity? If yes, which would it be? I guess, making a hexagon out of your data would give the periodic, plane filling object. Or do you expect discontinuous behaviour at the edges?

Comment: Would you please post a link to an example data set?

Comment: @JamesPhillips I've just added the array data that was used to create the image.

Comment: What do you mean by "the plane [you] wish to model"?  Your data would be very boring if it were all in one plane...

Comment: @DavisHerring - sorry, I should say 'surface'

Comment: The spikes in that data are openly hostile to Fourier analysis.  You can save some modes by doing it anisotropically, since the _x_ dependence is so much stronger than the _y_.  You might also consider working in log space if that makes sense for your data and the method.

Comment: @mikuszefski I have two kinds of datasets, (defining the x-axis as the base of the triangle pictured above, with x=0 at the centre) some are symmetric in reflection in x=0, some are anti-symmetric, so I guess I need both solutions. Great idea about tiling the plane, while all out discontinuities should be avoidable, I think there may be some fairly large spikes near the edges and corners though which might cause problems, as DavisHerring has noted.

Comment: @DavisHerring Thank you very much for the tips! I will look into working in log space to see if it could be viable.
  
  
My reason for looking for a Fourier expansion is that I want to use an approximation of this surface in an analytic integral. The integrand will be a product of the form: (the equation describing the surface)*(a huge linear sum of e^i(ax+by) terms). Having the surface described by sines and cosines would therefore be convenient, though for the reasons you have mentioned perhaps I should look for an alternative convenient basis.

Comment: If you consider the spikes as outliers they can be dealt with in [robust regression](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html)

Comment: concerning the basis, something like `exp( I* (k1 * x + k2*( x/2. + sqrt(3)/2. * y ) ) )` should be the one. Same thing if you go to `sin` and `cos`. The allowed `k`'s are given by your periodicity and symmetry of course.

Comment: @mikuszefski unfortunately the spikes aren't outliers in this case! They're actually perhaps the most important part of the data - which is why I am reconsidering Fourier expansion. It's a trade off it seems. A sin/ cosine series would be great for my next step, but perhaps not fit the data well (not without too many terms anyway). A polynomial fit might be simple to fit to the data and approx it well... but might make the next step of my calculation much more complicated.  
  
I think I will have to look into other bases and assess their simplicity for fitting and calcuation.

Comment: A comment on the spikes would have been too long, so I posted it as answer, although it is not a full answer to your original question. I would, hence, split the problem in low frequency Fourier and independent spikes.

Comment: If you just want to integrate the surface times a bunch of plane waves, can't you just use the mesh data directly as a piecewise-constant function and use an analytic integral over each triangle?

Comment: @DavisHerring I thought about this. These integrals are of quantum mechanical wavefunctions in a peturbing field (the above data is the field). The wavefunctions form an othogonal basis over the triangle - i.e. the integrals of them alone will be zero. These integrals are to calculate matrix elements for Fermi's golden rule: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/imgqua/golden2.gif The uneven distribution of the field is what allows coupling between states and a non-zero integral (it basically disturbs the otherwise perfect cancellation).  [continued]

Comment: They may be 0 integrated over the whole triangle, but they won't be 0 over the individual cells.

Comment: @DavisHerring The very high energy wavefunctions are very high frequency and self similar, so the mesh would not be high enough resolution to give meaningful results when each triangle contains many periods of the waves.
I am wondering now if the wavefunctions themselves could be a suitable basis for Fourier-esque expansion/ approximation of the field.

Comment: @DavisHerring Due to their self similar nature, I think in some cases they would be 0, when the cells align with the boundaries of the pattern

Comment: I don't think you can get meaningful information about frequencies that much higher than the sample spacing anyway.

Comment: @DavisHerring I think it is possible/ meaningful: I actually have much more precise data - the above is heavily down-sampled data for testing. The field is typically slowly varying and smooth, the example above is unusually rapidly varying. I think in most cases, a linear or quadratic approximation in each region would be reasonable. However, I am keen to have an approx in terms of sines and cosines because I have several million of these integrals to calculate, and I have a mathematical 'trick' that would make the calculation _much_ faster if I could represent the field in this form :)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing stops you from doing normal linear least squares with whatever basis you like.  (You'll have to work out the periodicity you want, as mikuszefski said.)  The lack of samples outside the triangle will naturally blind the method to the function's behavior out there.  You probably want to weight the samples according to the area of their mesh cell, to avoid overfitting the corners.

Answer (score 2):

Here some code that might help to fit periodic spikes. That also shows the use of the base `x, x/2+ sqrt(3)/2 * y`. The flat part can then be handled by low order Fourier. I hope that gives an idea. (BTW I agree with Davis Herring that area weighting is a good idea). For the fit, I guess, good initial guesses are crucial.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import numpy as np

def gauss(x,s):
    return np.exp(-x**2/(2.*s**2))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.15)
Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.15)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
kX=np.sin(X)
kY=np.sin(0.5*X+0.5*np.sqrt(3.)*Y)
R = np.sqrt(kX**2 + kY**2)
Z = gauss(R,.4)

#~ surf = ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, linewidth=1)
surf= ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1,linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: periodic spikes]